# Spring Boot XML serialisation of List query

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to return XML from a `@RestController`. The XML is a serialised `List` of `Car`.

The XML serialisation is not working how I expected. The serialisation does not use the Object name as the element name `<Car>...</Car>`, it just uses `<item>...</item>`. And I cannot work out how to change this behaviour.

Simple example is:

I have included the following dependency in the POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Car class:

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Car
{
    private final long id;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
}
```

CarService class:

```java
@Service
public class CarService
{
    public List<Car> findAll()
    {
        var cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

        cars.add(new Car(1, "Ford", "Fiesta"));
        cars.add(new Car(2, "Ford", "Mustang"));
        cars.add(new Car(3, "Ford", "GT40"));

        return cars;
    }
}
```

CarController class:

```java
@RestController
public class CarController
{
    private final CarService carService;

    public CarController(CarService carService)
    {
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/cars")
    public List<Car> getCars()
    {
        return carService.findAll();
    }
}
```

HTTP request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/cars
Accept: application/xml
```

I am getting:

```xml
<List>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Fiesta</model>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>GT40</model>
    </item>
</List>
```

And I am expecting:

```xml
<List>
    <Car>
        <id>1</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Fiesta</model>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <id>2</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <id>3</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>GT40</model>
    </Car>
</List>
```

I have also tried changing the Car class to this, but it had no effect:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="car")
public class Car
{
    private final long id;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
}
```

Also ideally I want the root element to be `<Cars></Cars>`, but I can't even get the items with the correct wrapper at the moment. I get the feeling I am missing something very simple, but cannot see what.

Spring boot project created with [these options](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.2.4.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=13&groupId=com.example&artifactId=xml-demo&name=xml-demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.xml-demo&dependencies=web,lombok)

Simple example project [on GitHub](https://github.com/moose56/stackoverflow-xml-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out your project and added a wrapper for the list of cars to set as `JacksonXmlRootElement` and define the list of cars as an attribute of that class:

**Cars class:**

```java
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Cars")
public class Cars {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Car")
    private List<Car> cars;
}

@Data
class Car {
    private final long id;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
}
```

**Service:**

```java
@Service
public class CarService {
    public Cars findAll() {
        var cars = new Cars();

        cars.setCars(
                List.of(
                        new Car(1, "Ford", "Fiesta"),
                        new Car(2, "Ford", "Mustang"),
                        new Car(3, "Ford", "GT40"))
        );

        return cars;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```java
@RestController
public class CarController
{
    private final CarService carService;

    public CarController(CarService carService)
    {
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/cars")
    public Cars getCars()
    {
        return carService.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <id>1</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Fiesta</model>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <id>2</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <id>3</id>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>GT40</model>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

I have used `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` to prevent the list of cars being wrapped in an element as well.

Comment: thanks, that works for me. Is this a common pattern?

Comment: Yes; Jackson XML & JAXB require a root element to be present. The reason is that valid XML requires a single root element to encapsulate all child elements.